# Pybind11: Passing a Python list to C-style array

Tags: python, c++, arrays, pybind11

I would like to pass a Python list to a constructor which takes C-style arrays.
How should that work. The problem is that the C-style array is essentially a pointer. Furthermore, the array has dimension n x n, i.e. it is a multi-dimensional array.

```
     PYBIND11_MODULE(matrix_class_bind, m){
         py::class_<matrix_class<double>>(m, "matrix_class")
         .def(py::init([](double x[3][3]){
          matrix_class<double> new_class(x);
          return new_class;}));
    }
```

On the python side it should be something like:

```
import matrix_class_bind as mcb    
a = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [1,1,1]]
mcb.matrix_class(a)
```

Comment: Check out [xtensor-python](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor-python). You'd need to write an interface function that takes an `xt::pyarray<double>` reference and pass to your C-style function by taking the address of the first element similar to a vector/STL array.

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation about custom contructors? http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#custom-constructors. This would allow you to write a wrapper that converts e.g. list to raw array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the matrix as a pointer, you could pass it using `py::list`, if your aim is to access the matrix as a C array.

```
class matrix_class {
    public:
        static const int n = 3;
        int carray[n][n];
        py::list list;
        matrix_class(const py::list &list) : list(list) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                py::list l = list[i].cast<py::list>();
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    int p = l[j].cast<int>();
                    carray[i][j] = p;
                }
            }
    }
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(matrix_class_bind, m) {
    py::class_<matrix_class>(m, "matrix_class")
        .def(py::init<const py::list &>());
}
```